# DATEDIFF Function Issue in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying call another measure from datediff function, but I am getting below error.

Below is what I have done.

[image]

My **SelectTime** Measure definition is as below.

[image]

Also I have an Intermediate table called Interval, Though which I will be selecting the TimePeriod by putting it in a slicer.

[image]

Can someone please explain me what am I missing here, TIA.

Comment: You are sending the whole range to the datediff fucntion. You need to use HASONEVALUE in a variable in MyDateDiff, to make sure it only send one value

Comment: Hi Jon, I have edited the Question, Can please advise now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, interval in DateDiff must be a constant, and can not be a variable. It's a limitation of DAX language which I hope Microsoft will improve at some point.

For now, you can use a different approach.

```
SelectTime = SELECTEDVALUE(Interval[TimePeriod])
```

Then:

```
MyDateDiff = 
VAR Start_Date = DATE(1984,11,01)
VAR End_Date = DATE(1089, 08, 08)
RETURN
SWITCH(
   [SelectTime],
    "Day", DATEDIFF(Start_Date, End_Date, DAY),
    "Month", DATEDIFF(Start_Date, End_Date, MONTH),
    "Week", DATEDIFF(Start_Date, End_Date, WEEK),
    DATEDIFF(Start_Date, End_Date, YEAR)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me that its a limitation of DAX that we cannot use a variable inside a DATEDIFF function for Interval parameter.